# ASP.NET Core and Angular - SSR

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

...and it's not working. :(

I create ASP.NET Core app from angular template. I actualy followed these directions from these [official ssr docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#server-side-rendering)

1. Setting up `ASPNETCORE_Environment` variable
2. Run `dotnet new angular`
3. Modify `Startup.cs` and add `UseSpaPrerendering`
4. Add settings to `.angular-cli.json`
5. Add `tsconfig.server.json`
6. Add `app.server.module.ts`
7. Add `main.server.ts`
8. Modify csproj `BuildServerSideRenderer` option
9. Run `npm i` in `ClientApp` directory

In Development it's work fine. But after production build it work's like in development, ssr not working. Angular continues to run on client.

My steps to build:

1. Run `dotnet build -c Release -o out`
2. Angular builds without errors (after build in `out` dir, creates 2 angular builds - `dist` and `dist-server` (`dist-server` size is 32Kb)
3. Run `dotnet ssr.dll`

These basic steps for SSR. But I modify `main.ts` and `main.server.ts` files, add these to `extraProviders`
for main.ts

```
{ provide: 'OS', useValue: 'Client' }
```

for main.server.ts

```
{ provide: 'OS', useValue: 'Server' }
```

and modify `home` component
    import { Component, Inject  } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {

  os: string = null;

  constructor(@Inject('OS') public osinject: string) {
    console.log(osinject);
    this.os = osinject;
  }
}
```

Actualy after build and run my project, i should have seen 'Hello Server', but i see 'Hello Client'.

I tried create 2 times from scratch, tried run in docker container, tried run other projects with ssr (find in github). But it all not working for me

```
> dotnet --version
2.1.403

> node --version
v8.11.3
```

Whats went wrong guys?

[Here my repo](https://github.com/extremecodetv/aspnet-core-angular-ssr) (just in case)

Comment: Actually , your code runs flawlessly for me . Are you inspecting the "Hello, Client!" by viewing the page source rendered from server ?

Comment: yep, `Hello, Client`, and source not rendered on server, but on the client

Comment: If the page source initially rendered by server contains `<app-home><h1>Hello, Server!</h1>` , that means  SSR is working. SSR rendering means rendering on server and send them to client (which means it will then run on client side ) , not mean to disable client side rendering.